# Выборка с помощью метода GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Есть таблица `result` в БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как узнать имена участников, которые сдавали **два предмета** и получить их пару `subject/TestResult`?. В нашем случае два предмета сдавали **Иван** и **Игорь**, следовательно ответом будет:

```
математика 3 
русский язык 2  
математика 5  
русский язык 3
```

Знаю, что здесь в ход надо (скорее всего) пускать `GroupBy`, но к сожалению я плохо знаком с ним. Но) мне удалось узнать сколько таких участников - сколько участников сдавало **два предмета**:

```
    dbEntities dataContext = new dbEntities();
    var countPart = dataContext.results.GroupBy(a => a.name).Select(a => a.Select( b => b.subject)).Where(a => a.Count() == 2).Count();

    Console.WriteLine(countPart);
```

Как теперь получить не просто количество, а их значения `subject/TestResult`, для дальнейшей обработки в `foreach`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать это можно например так:

```
var data = new[]
        {
            new { Name = "Ваня", Subject="математика", TestResult = 5 },
            new { Name = "Иван", Subject="математика", TestResult = 3 },
            new { Name = "Иван", Subject="русский язык", TestResult = 2 },
            new { Name = "Игорь", Subject="математика", TestResult = 5 },
            new { Name = "Игорь", Subject="русский язык", TestResult = 3 },
        };

var res = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
              .Where(x=> x.Count() == 2)
              .SelectMany(x => x.AsEnumerable()).Select(x => new { x.Subject, x.TestResult });

foreach (var item in res)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```